# Given that browsers are limited to 6 concurrent connections, can an XmlHttpRequest timeout while it's still waiting in the queue?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

From what I understand, browsers will not open more than 6 concurrent connections to a given host, and additional requests are queued for later. Given this information, how does the timeout property on an XmllHttpRequest work? When does that timer start? Will a browser allow a request timeout while it's still waiting in the queue? For example, if I send 7 total requests, each with a 1 second timeout, and the first 6 requests take exactly 1 second to complete, will the 7th request timeout? I hope this is clear. Any links to actual documentation would be very helpful.

Comment: Seems like a question you could test pretty definitively.  Try it!

Comment: I did test it actually and I was able to confirm that the 7th request does in fact time out.